# Dockerfile option that defaults to background running (detached)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there an option you can specify in a Dockerfile that defaults containers built with it to run detached.

This would lead to the same outcome as the -d in:

```
docker run -d <imagename>
```

So that

```
docker run <imagename>
```

would run detached by default.

Comment: You mean think about `docker-compose`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of Dockerfile is to build the image.  How to run the image is controlled by "docker run" command. There is no option available in Dockerfile as per Docker documentation.

Comment: I was chasing a fake issue